# How does static sleep method of Thread class work without access to 'this' reference?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, this, sleep

I have some confusion about static methods. Static methods does not have access to `this` reference. (In Java, `this` is a reference that refers to the current object.)

When there is a call to `Thread.sleep(millis)`, **how does the static sleep method of `Thread` class choose which thread to sleep?** `Thread.sleep(long millis)` is a static method and does not have access to `this` reference.

```
public class CurrentThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

        System.out.println("Current thread: " + t);

        //change the name of the thread
        t.setName("My thread");
        System.out.println("After name change: " + t);

        try {
            for (int n = 5; n > 0; n--) {
                System.out.println(n);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()

Comment: Magic in native code.

Comment: this is not a reference variable,its simply a reference

Comment: Better to know how notify choose which thread to wake up and how wait works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When there is a call to Thread.sleep(millis), how does the static sleep method of Thread class choose to which thread to sleep.

The spec of Thread.sleep is that it suspends the *current* thread, i.e. the one that called the `sleep` method.

Comment: Is there any way in JAVA to know from where a static method is called?

Comment: @abcdef12 in any method (static or not) you can construct a `new Throwable()` and inspect its stack trace, but that's quite a slow operation so not something you want to be doing too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

> "The `Thread.sleep()` method essentially interacts with the thread
>   scheduler to put the current thread into a wait state for the required
>   interval."

Source: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/sleep.shtml

Answer (score 0):

> When there is a call to Thread.sleep(millis), how does the static sleep method of Thread class choose which thread to sleep?

It chooses the current thread. The one that is calling the method. The one returned by `Thread.currentThread().`

> Thread.sleep(long millis) is a static method and does not have access to this reference variable.

I agree. So? It doesn't need it.